# Retrieving Phone Numbers that are not deleted from the Android Contact List

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to retrieve phone numbers from the ContactsContract that are not marked to be deleted.

```
@Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(
            this,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            },
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DELETED + "==0",
            null,
            null);
}
```

However, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: deleted (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT data1 FROM view_data data LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT data_usage_stat.data_id as STAT_DATA_ID, SUM(data_usage_stat.times_used) as times_used, MAX(data_usage_stat.last_time_used) as last_time_used FROM data_usage_stat GROUP BY data_usage_stat.data_id) as data_usage_stat ON (STAT_DATA_ID=data._id) WHERE (1 AND mimetype_id=5) AND ((deleted==0))
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

[The documentation for ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#CONTENT_URI) states that the data records will be combined with the associated raw contact and aggregate contact data. But "deleted" is not there. Why and how can I get only the phone numbers that are not deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data URI projection does not have the DELETED column, in any case your query should only retrieve the phone numbers of the contacts which are not deleted. Are you able to get phone numbers of deleted raw contacts?

Comment: Interesting that it is not documented anywhere.. Or I cannot find it. Exactly, when you ask through ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, you receive the phone numbers that are not deleted.

Comment: Check the discussion under delete, its not very straight forward but you should be able to get the picture https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making query against wrong table. Try to change `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` to `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: But in that case you will get a contact row, which does not have the phone number. It only has HAS_PHONE_NUMBER column. And for each contact you need to requery the associated Data rows to get the phone numbers. That's what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and ended my searching for fastest solution to retrieve contacts.

```
public static List<ContactDTO> getPhone(Context context){
        List<ContactDTO> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactDTO>();
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver(); 
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { 
                ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };

        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String filter = ""+ ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0 and " + Phone.TYPE +"=" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;     
        String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";// LIMIT " + limit + " offset " + lastId + "";

        Cursor phoneCur = cr.query(uri, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
        while(phoneCur.moveToNext()){
             ContactDTO dto = new ContactDTO();
             dto.setName("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
             dto.setMobileNo("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
             dto.setPhotoUrl("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI)));
             dto.setContactId("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID)));
             contactList.add(dto);
         }
         phoneCur.close();
        return contactList;
}
```

where ContactDTO is Simple POJO class.